# how to check for a pattern at the end of a line and delete new line

Tags: unix

I am trying to clean a file which looks like:

```
    insert....;
    update.....;
    del
    ete.......;
    in
    sert........;
```

I would like to remove the new line characters for the lines that don't end with semicolon and after cleaning the file should like:

```
    insert.......;
    update.......;
    delete.......;
    insert........;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
$ cat in
insert....;
update.....;
del
ete.......;
in
sert........;
$ awk '{if ($0 ~ /;$/) {print} else {printf ("%s", $0)}}' in
insert....;
update.....;
delete.......;
insert........;
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @Jens answer I used `sed`

```
$ cat test.txt 
insert....;
upd
ate.....;
del
ete.......;
insert........;

$ sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' -e 's/;/;\n/g' < test.txt > test2.txt

$ cat test2.txt 
insert....;
update.....;
delete.......;
insert........;
```

This does produce a blank line at the end of the file though